# Create View in a Trigger

Tags: mysql, view, triggers, mysql-workbench

I have to use a view (not already created, because it's needed within that UPDATE TRIGGER) in an UPDATE inside an UPDATE TRIGGER.

So this is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lunghezza_sentiero_datoderivato_UPDATE2
AFTER UPDATE ON TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

CREATE VIEW tempoOLD_NULL(IDsentiero, tempo) AS 
    SELECT IDsentiero, tempo
    FROM SENTIERO
    WHERE tempo IS NULL and SENTIERO.IDsentiero IN (SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                                                    FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                                                    WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa);

CREATE VIEW lunghezzaOLD_NULL(IDsentiero, lunghezza) AS 
    SELECT IDsentiero, lunghezza
    FROM SENTIERO
    WHERE lunghezza IS NULL and SENTIERO.IDsentiero IN (SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                                                        FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                                                        WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa);

IF (NEW.lunghezza<>OLD.lunghezza) and (NEW.lunghezza is not null) THEN

    UPDATE SENTIERO
    SET lunghezza=lunghezza - OLD.lunghezza + NEW.lunghezza
    WHERE IDsentiero IN (SELECT DISTINCT IDsentiero
                         FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht
                         WHERE NEW.IDtappa=sht.IDtappa) and IDsentiero NOT IN (SELECT IDsentiero
                                                                               FROM lunghezzaOLD_NULL);

    UPDATE SENTIERO
    SET lunghezza=NEW.lunghezza
    WHERE IDsentiero IN (SELECT IDsentiero
                         FROM lunghezzaOLD_NULL);



END IF;
```

**When i COMMENT both 2 CREATE VIEW** all runs... but i need that views.. so, please help me! (create view outside the trigger? but i need to create a view on every update, because the NULL value change along the time)

**ADDENDUM FOR TABLES AND EXAMPLES AS REQUESTED:**

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SENTIERO` (
  `IDsentiero` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'identificativo del sentiero' ,
  `lunghezza` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'dato derivato' ,
  `tempo` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'dato derivato' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDsentiero`) );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TAPPA` (
  `IDtappa` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'identificativo tappa' ,
  `lunghezza` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'Lunghezza espressa in km' ,
  `tempo` FLOAT NULL COMMENT 'La quantità di ore stimate per arrivare alla tappa' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDtappa`) );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA` (
  `IDtappa` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `IDsentiero` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDtappa`, `IDsentiero`) );
```

One 'TAPPA' can be included in one or more **'SENTIERO'**, one **'SENTIERO'** includes one or more 'TAPPA'. 
Each **'SENTIERO'** has the sum of 'tempo' and 'lunghezza' of its one or more 'TAPPA'.
So when occurs an update on 'TAPPA', if 'tempo' and 'lunghezza' of that **'TAPPA'** have changed, i want to re-calculate the 'tempo' and 'lunghezza' for the one or more **'SENTIERO'** the updated **'TAPPA'** is related to.
See, **'SENTIERO'** has the SUM of its own **'TAPPA'**

```
SENTIERO                     |    SENTIERO_HA_TAPPA       |  TAPPA
IDsentiero tempo lunghezza   |    IDsentiero  IDtappa     |  IDtappa tempo lunghezza  
   0         3     20        |        0          1        |     1      3      20
   1         8     35        |        1          1        |     2      5      15
                             |        1          2        |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use views for this purpose.  It's not what they're intended for.

Instead, learn how to join tables properly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER lunghezza_sentiero_datoderivato_UPDATE2
AFTER UPDATE ON TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW

  IF (NEW.lunghezza <> OLD.lunghezza) AND (NEW.lunghezza IS NOT NULL) THEN
    -- note that this condition will not be entered if `OLD.lunghezza` IS NULL
    -- irrespective of NEW.lunghezza.  Perhaps you want to use the NULL-safe
    -- equality operator <=> instead?

    UPDATE SENTIERO AS s
      JOIN SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA AS sht USING (IDsentiero)
    SET    s.lunghezza = CASE
             WHEN s.lunghezza IS NULL THEN NEW.lunghezza
             ELSE s.lunghezza - OLD.lunghezza + NEW.lunghezza
           END
    WHERE  sht.IDtappa = NEW.IDtappa;

  END IF
```

Comment: Hey there, thank you, the UPDATE i'm sure will work, it's useful for my purpose :)
i have a doubt about YOUR COMMENT: I want to update if 2 conditions are satisfied.
(1) The new value of lunghezza must be NOT THE SAME of the old value
(2) The new value cannot be NULL

Thank you

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana: Indeed, but if the old value was `NULL` then `NEW <> OLD` will evaluate to `NULL` and the `UPDATE` will not be executed.  You should instead use something like `NOT NEW <=> OLD`, which will only be true if the value has changed.

Comment: Anyway it doesn't work that query... i'm still working on it.
In brief: i'm working on derived data (**TEMPO** and **LUNGHEZZA** are on both **SENTIERO** and **TAPPA** tables); when i do an **UPDATE ON TAPPA**, i should **UPDATE TEMPO AND/OR LUNGHEZZA on SENTIERO.**
You can think **SENTIERO** as a "path" with multiple "points".. and one "point" (**TAPPA**) can be included in multiple "paths". So, update on "point", find its "path" within is included (or more than one path), update **TEMPO AND/OR LUNGHEZZA** on "path".
I want to be sure you know what i'm going to do

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana: To be honest, it's very difficult to picture.  The easiest thing may be if you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16256250/edit) to include a sample of the data as it currently stands, and the data as it should ultimately be when faced with some particular update(s).