# Create view after insert trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, view

I have two tables companies (id,company_name) and users (id,company_id,user_name);

Now I want to create a view when data is inserted in companies table.

I used following two ways but getting same error in both the cases. Error is :

```
#1422 - Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.
```

First Query is :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER testInsert 
    AFTER INSERT ON companies
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   CREATE VIEW test(user_name) AS 
    SELECT user_name
    FROM users;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I tried creating procedure first and called that procedure in trigger like this

```
create procedure createView() 
 create view vt as select * from users; 


 CREATE TRIGGER `testInsert3` AFTER INSERT ON `companies`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   CALL createView();
END;
```

Please help me guys.

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

```
    please refer this link, i think this will help you

    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256250/create-view-in-a-trigger


try creating the view like this 


DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER testInsert 
    AFTER INSERT ON companies
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

   EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW test(user_name) AS SELECT user_name
    FROM users')
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```